# Automation testing using selenium and python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to automation testing. I am learning from last 2 months. My company needs a program to check multiple URLs and perform tests on them to see if the sites are working or not. If not working, then a report should be generated and an email should be sent to all with the report. I made a program to browse multiple URLS and also to should an email using SMTP. But the issue is that, I am unable to use the same code to login to multiple URLS. Also, I need to send no-reply email. I am unable to do so. Please help me if anyone is aware of it. I am using selenium and python language for my program.

Comment: You asked two questions in one, something about multiple urls and how to send emails from no-reply. What is your problem with the multiple urls? Could you shows some code? Do you get errors?

Comment: I have successfully sorted my issue of multiple URLS. But still I am unable to sort the issue of sending email to users from a no-reply email. Please help if you can

Answer (score 0):

With Python you could use [subTest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests) to create a single unit tests which loops over multiple inputs.

```
def test_login_multiple_urls(self):
    # setup driver here
    urls = ["http://server1.com", "http://server2.com", "http://server3.com"]
    for url in urls:
        with self.subTest(url=url):
            driver.get(url)
            # more setup
            # some actions to test
            # some assert
```

For sending as emails as no-reply define the FROM field to a no-reply@example.org mail address:

```
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Test results'
msg['From'] = 'no-reply@example.org'
```

Read more in the Python email documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html